# RSelenium WebDriver TimeoutException after ClickElement

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I'm using the Selenium WebDriver in R to parse some online data.  I originally wrote the script a few months ago, and it worked great.  However, I ran it again today and I receive the following error after running `ClickElement()`:

```
Error:   Summary: ScriptTimeout
     Detail: A script did not complete before its timeout expired.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException
```

I'm using Chrome as my browser, and have updated to the newest version (2.20) of ChromeDriver (I was using 2.19 when I wrote the script).  This error is peculiar because it occurs pretty late in my script, after I have already used `ClickElement()` multiple other times.  The element being clicked is a download button.  Selenium completes the click and starts the download, but then throws the above error after a few minutes.  At this point, the script continues.

I can only think of a few possible issues:

- The ChromeDriver update has broken something.  I've tried it with both 2.19 and 2.20, and I'm unsure how to test this further.
- Some issue outside of my understanding of Selenium.  From some experimenting and trying to Google similar problems, I've decided that it might have something to do with the download process itself, i.e. the driver freezes up because the download is currently running on the page.

I'm not sure what is going on, and I don't know enough about Selenium to troubleshoot it effectively.  What can I do?  I imagine that I'll need an alternative way to perform the download, or at least a way to click the element while ignoring the `ScriptTimeout` error.  I receive the same error when I try to send the enter key to the element as well.

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar issue but I can't figure out.

Try this after your clickElement code

```
Sys.sleep(2)
```